# Accept two parameters with same name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters, guid

I have this code now

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid? id, string alias)
{
    var room = db.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomLink == id || r.Alias == alias);

    if (room != null)
    {
    //some code with room...
    }
}
```

My goal is to accept two kinds url (parameters) in my action.

String

```
www.example.com/Rooms/Aliasstring
```

Guid

```
www.example.com/Rooms/387ecbbf-90e0-4b72-8768-52c583fc715
```

I have `id` in routes so alias is always null.

Would be nice if I could do it like this (if parameter is a Guid OR parameter is a string OR both Null)

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid? id, string? id)
{
    var room = db.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomLink == id || r.Alias == id);
}
```

But I can't have two `id`'s as parameter.

Routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My model

```
public Guid RoomLink { get; set; }
public string Alias { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid your problem with routing by means of simple checking your the input parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(string input)
{
    Guid guidOutput;
    bool isId = Guid.TryParse(input, out guidOutput);
    bool isAlias = !isId;

   var room = isId ?
              db.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomLink == input) :
              db.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Alias == input);

}
```